# Objective C getting pickerview values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

another Objective-C one for you, probably pretty obvious but I have been at this for a few days now, and can't get it to work after trawling through similar problems on here and elsewhere!

Pretty much I have a 5 segment picker which, when a button is clicked, an alert sheet is shown which once accepted grabs the values of the picker wheels. Easy huh, yet I cant get it to work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong... Some code below... it's probably pretty bad... but it's all pretty new to me so any help would be appreciated. All this is done without using InterfaceBuilder by the way.

Everything up to the loop after the action sheet works fine... I just can't get the values out!

(ps, i hope the formatting works! And I have changed some of my namings and that but all should be right)

Thanks!

MyFile.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView * thePickerView;
    NSArray *thePickerValues;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *thePickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *thePickerValues;

- (void)buildPicker;
- (void)doAction;

@end
```

MyFile.m

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize thePickerView;
@synthesize thePickerValues;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",nil];
    thePickerValues = values;
    [values release];
    [self buildPicker];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 5;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.thePickerValues count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.thePickerValues objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)buildPicker
{
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f,130.0f,320.0,100.0f);
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerView release];
}



- (void)doAction
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah blah"]
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No!"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes!"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
    [actionSheet release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(!(buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]))
    {
        NSLog(@"Get the picker values");
        for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)
        {
            NSInteger *selectedValue = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
            NSLog(@"Wheel : %i Value : %i", i, selectedValue);
            [selectedValue release];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so, having played about a bit more, I am starting to think I am not connecting to the picker. For example, I have moved the code to get the values into its own action which is called in that loop there. I have also changed the array temporarily to be a, b, c etc..

The results seem to indicate that no matter what you choose it is just coming up with the selectedRowInComponent as 0

Any more ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer: thePickerView is nil. I don't see you assigning a value to it, right?

Comment: Possibly, I _think_ I am assigning the value here...

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.thePickerValues objectAtIndex:row];
}

Comment: I think Steven's right. If `thePickerView` is nil, any messages you send to it will evaluate to nil, or 0. You probably didn't connect the view to your outlet in the xib file. (You may have to declare the property IBOutlet for it to appear.)

Comment: In buildPicker, just assign pickerView to thePickerView: `self.thePickerView = pickerView`

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
NSInteger *selectedValue = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
```

You should be aware that an `NSInteger` is just a name for an `int` (actually, the underlying type depends on the OS but it's always a concrete type and not an Objective C object). Or put another way, it's not a pointer. Try:

```
NSInteger selectedValue = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
```

I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler warning about this.

Comment: I did, and have been trying to find another way of getting it to work! Shall try it now ta....

Comment: Okay, so this sorts out the warning however now I am returning 0 for each wheel.

(oops itchy enter key finger!)

Comment: @rich - it helps if you add compiler warnings to your question - it saves people having to read and find errors in code that the compiler has already pointed out.

Comment: @Abizern Sorry, I didn't think to do that... thanks for the heads up though(!)

Answer (score 0):

An NSInteger is not an object. It's plain old data. Look up its definition now. Go on, command-double click the symbol in your source file. Or option-double click to look it up in the reference manual.

And this should do it.

```
NSInteger selectedValue = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
NSLog(@"Wheel : %i Value : %i", i, selectedValue);
// [selectedValue release];
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, NSInteger is not an object.

```
NSInteger *selectedValue = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
```

What is happening in this line is that `selectedRowInComponent:` is returning a number indicating *the index of* the selected row. Because you are assigning it to an `NSInteger` *pointer* instead, the computer is using the value as a memory address. (When you declare `Whatever *foo` that means that `foo` contains a memory address, and `*foo` is the value at that address.)

If you tried to dereference (get the value pointed to by) `selectedValue`, your app will likely crash. Or worse, not crash, and return whatever junk is at that arbitrary address.

More importantly, you are mixing up what the method returns (the index) with what you want (the value).

Here's what you need:

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
NSString *selectedValue = [thePickerValues objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
```

Now you've got what you want in `selectedValue`, and can put it in your action sheet.

Comment: This makes sense indeed. However trying that I am now getting something like this for each:

Wheel : 4
selectedRow : 0
selectedValue : 291628

Comment: Ah wait, thats because I was using %i instead of %@
Anyway, I'm still getting 0 as the selectedValue with this